# Creating multi-index dataframe (with some nuance)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a multi-index dataframe using pandas to look like the one below where I have 'Close' as a property of Attributes, and 'SPY' and 'FNSR' as properties of Symbols. Both SPY and FNSR are the sub-columns beneath the 'Close' column. The values of each symbol corresponds to different dates.

```
Attributes   Close     
Symbols      SPY FNSR
Date                 
2011-01-01     2   21
2011-01-02     3   22
```

In attempt to build this, I wrote the code below:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Attributes' : ['Close','Close'],
    'Date' : [datetime(2011,1,1),datetime(2011,1,2)],
    'Symbols': ['SPY','FNSR'],
    'SPY' : [2,3],
    'FNSR': [21,22],
})

todayPrice2 = df2.set_index(['Date','Attributes']).stack().unstack([1,2])
```

The output that I get is somewhat close to what I want but then I end up with "Symbols" as its own sub-column underneath "Close", and not as an index.

```
Attributes   Close         
           Symbols SPY FNSR
Date                       
2011-01-01     SPY   2   21
2011-01-02    FNSR   3   22
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either filter your dataframe after the set_index() using:

```
todayPrice2 = df2.set_index(['Date','Attributes'])[['SPY','FNSR']].stack().unstack([1,2])
todayPrice2
```

Output:

```
Attributes Close     
             SPY FNSR
Date                 
2011-01-01     2   21
2011-01-02     3   22
```

Or drop column using tuple notation:

```
todayPrice2 = df2.set_index(['Date','Attributes']).stack().unstack([1,2])\
                 .drop(('Close','Symbols'), axis=1)
print(todayPrice2)
```

Output:

```
Attributes Close     
             SPY FNSR
Date                 
2011-01-01     2   21
2011-01-02     3   22
```

And, if you really want those axis naming:

```
todayPrice2 = df2.set_index(['Date','Attributes']).stack().unstack([1,2])\
                 .drop(('Close','Symbols'), axis=1).rename_axis(['Attributes', 'Symbols'], axis=1)
print(todayPrice2)
```

Output:

```
Attributes Close     
Symbols      SPY FNSR
Date                 
2011-01-01     2   21
2011-01-02     3   22
```

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are duplicated in column and rows. Drop `'Symbols': ['SPY','FNSR']`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Attributes' : ['Close','Close'],
    'Date' : [datetime(2011,1,1),datetime(2011,1,2)],
    'SPY' : [2,3],
    'FNSR': [21,22],
})

df2.set_index(['Date','Attributes']).unstack(1).swaplevel(axis=1)
```

Alternatively, organize data as

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date' : [datetime(2011,1,1),datetime(2011,1,2)]*2,
    'Symbols':['SPY']*2+['FNSR']*2,
    'Close' : [2,3,21,22],
})

df2.set_index(['Date','Symbols']).unstack(1)
```